# How to pause game when user turn off screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have problem with one of my games. This is time based puzzle game and I have problem with it. When user press on/off button on Android device game doesn`t stop, but timer goes on and on till game over. When user turn on screen again, he can see game over screen. But I want to make scenario when user press on/off button game will pause.

Any suggestions? I`m pretty new in programming so please explain me very basic method to do this.

Thanks all!

Edit. Timer code

```
private void initializeProgressBar() {
    //initialize progressbar
    progress = ApplicationConstants.GAME_TIME;

    mProgress = (ProgressBarDetermininate) findViewById(R.id.progressDeterminate);
    mProgress.setMax(progress);
    mProgress.setProgress(progress );
    timer = new Timer();
    progressBarUpdateTask = new ProgressBarUpdateTask();
    timer.schedule(progressBarUpdateTask, 20, 20);
}

class ProgressBarUpdateTask extends TimerTask {
      @Override
      public void run() {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progress-=1;
            if(progress==0)
            {
                TimeOver();
            }
            mProgress.setProgress(progress);
        }

        });
      }

    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.timer.cancel();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Pause your game in `onStop()` or `onPause()` (depending on your need) in the Activity context your game is running in.

Comment: I add this.timer.cancel(); in onPause... But how to resume timer?

Comment: According to the documentation: "When a timer is no longer needed, users should call cancel(), which releases the timer's thread and other resources. Timers not explicitly cancelled may hold resources indefinitely."

Comment: So you cannot resume a `java.util.Time` after `cancel()` is called. Just create your timer in `onResume()`

Comment: Thank you alenz316. Now I was put timer code in onResume. But when I turn off screen and turn on again, timer start again from the start. This will be nice cheats in game if users will discover this :) Any suggestions?

Comment: Just save the time when you cancel the timer, then use that when you create the new one. ;)

Comment: Thanks! I hope I will find some useful tutorials about this. I`m completely beginner :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using android's activity...

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Resume the timer or show a button for the user to press when ready
    // !!! Also check if timer exits because onResume is called before onCreate!!!
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Pause the timer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to detect the user presence, here's an example

At beginning of your game start the `LockService`

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockService.class));
```

---

**LockService.java**

```
public class LockService extends Service {
    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
LockService getService() {
return LockService.this;
}
}
}
```

---

Then finally the `BroadcastReceiver`  where you can stop your game.

**ScreenReceiver.java**

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    Log.e("LOB","onReceive");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = false;

           /* PAUSE THE GAME HERE*/

            Log.e("LOB","wasScreenOn"+wasScreenOn);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = true;
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){

        }
    }
}
```

As correctly mentioned in other answers, you can also use the  [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) method

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // stop the game
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you press screen off or Power button onPause method of the application will be called and when you again press Power button, applications onResume method will be called, you should pause timer in onPause and resume it in onResume.